# Python insert number in list sequence

Tags: python, list

I am trying to insert a number into a list of a sequence of numbers, for some reason this small program just sits there consuming CPU power... no idea why it's not working:

```
number = 5
lst = [4,5,6]
if all(x > number for x in lst):
    lst.insert(0,number)
elif all(x < number for x in lst):
    lst.append(number)
else:
    for i,v in enumerate(lst):
        if v>number:
            lst.insert(i-1,number)
print (lst)
```

expected output:

```
lst = [4,5,5,6]
```

Comment: If the original list is already sorted, I'd suggest to iterate the list and insert `x` before the first element which is equal or grater.

Comment: @Don yea good point thanks

Comment: You shouldn't change a `list` while you are iterating over it. Your code is effectively never moving forward because you are constantly inserting a new number and `v` remains the same each time. It is better to create a new list.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're trying to add a number to a list and keep it sorted?

Comment: You can also have a look at `bisect` library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Comment: @Don That would not be a good idea for big lists, as the time complexity would be O(n).  If it's already sorted, a binary search can be done in O(log n) time.

Comment: Although it might not be the most efficient way of doing it you could just add the number an sort it. ej: `list = [1,3,2]` then add whatever you want `list.append(2)` and sort `list.sort()` this should output `[1,2,2,3]`

Comment: @JacobG. Good point! Note that documentation about `bisect.insert_left` states that after O(log n) for searching, it takes O(n) for inserting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *for* loop is inserting the number 5 into the middle of the list a theoretically infinite amount of times (or until you run out of whatever limited resource the list consumes, whichever happens first).

```
1) for i,v in enumerate(lst):
2)    if v>number:
3)       lst.insert(i-1,number)
```

On the first pass, line 1 starts the loop with v = 4 and i = 0.  Line 2 finds v is not greater than number.

On the second pass, line 1 continues the loop with v = 5 and i = 1.  Line 2 is also false.

Third pass, line 1: v = 6, i = 2.  Line 2 finds a true statement and moves to line 3.  Line 3 inserts the object referenced by *number* into position i - 1, inserting 5 into position 1 of the list.

At this point the list is:

```
lst = [4, *5*, **5**, 6]
```

The italicized 5 is the number you added to the list.  The bolded 5 is where the current pointer is, i = 2.  Notice that the 6 we just checked got moved forward with the insert.

Fourth pass: v = 6, i = 3.  Line 2 finds a true statement and moves to line 3.  Line 3 inserts the object referenced by *number* into position i - 1, inserting 5 into position 2 of the list.

At this point the list is:

```
lst = [4, 5, *5*, **5**, 6]
```

etc etc etc.

A quick fix:

```
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    if v > number:
        lst.insert(i-1, number)
        **break**
```

You're just checking for and adding a single number, so break out of the loop once you insert it, since you're done.

Comment: Won't run out of stack, list contents aren't stored there.

Comment: Had a few doubts about calling it stack.  Since I don't know the internal workings of Python objects and their limits just yet, I changed it to be more general.